# Newbie in Firefox Web extensions - asking for some directions

Tags: html, css, firefox-addon-webextensions

I would like to program a web extension for Firefox and I am aiming to make a bookmark visualization/organizer as close as possible to the old firefox addon **Viewmarks**: https://dottech.org/165778/how-to-display-bookmarks-as-thumbnails-in-firefox-tip/

I want someone to point me to the right direction regarding as what to research. 
So my question is: 
How can I approach the visual part of the page that opens and hosts the thumbnails of the bookmarks? Is it an HTML file stylized with CSS or something else entirely?

Thank you.

Comment: Try googling `Firefox Web Extensions`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension

Comment: I... already did, thanks. So is what I am describing an HTML stylized using CSS or something else?